# Group python dataframe and display all correspond values for each unique key in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, unique-key

I have the following dataset

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 7510 | 15 Jun 2020 |
| 7510 | 16 Jun 2020 |
| 7512 | 15 Jun 2020 |
| 7512 | 07 Jul 2020 |
| 7520 | 15 Jun 2020 |
| 7520 | 16 Aug 2020 |

I need to convert this to a dictionary which is quite straight forward, but need each unique id as a key and all corresponding values as values to the unique key.

for example;
**dictionary = {7510: ["15 Jun 2020", "16 Jun 2020"], 7512: ["15 Jun 2020", "07 Jul 2020"],
7520: ["15 Jun 2020", "16 Aug 2020"] }**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('id')['date'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{7510: ['15 Jun 2020', '16 Jun 2020'],
 7512: ['15 Jun 2020', '07 Jul 2020'],
 7520: ['15 Jun 2020', '16 Aug 2020']}
```